# Which connector to use?

Tags: connector

I want to connect two PCBs with four wires: VCC, GND, 2x I2C. Which connector is best suited for this application? I was thinking about an USB connector (and wire), but I am not sure if that is the best possibility. Therefore I wanted to ask if there are better connector types than USB for this application? VCC is 5V.

Comment: Do not use USB connector for non-usb signals. It will confuse people. Any simple connector will do, unless you have some high currents.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Can you suggest me a (small) connector with 4 Pins?

Comment: What do you expect from your connector: A huge number of mate/demate cycles? Low price? Mechanical stability? Low contact impedance? Small size? Ease of mate/demate? Pre-made cables available? Stackable? etc.

Comment: I would suggest any that you can salvage from surrounding electronic junk. Google "small 4 pin connector" and switch to images results, and choose whatever looks good to you.

Comment: A JST XH or PH connector should work for most cases.

Comment: I use MTA100 for I2C at work, which is 2.54 mm pitch like what Ignacio suggested. Really depends on what current you'll be pulling, what gauge wire you're using, etc.

Comment: @EugeneSh. makes an important point.  If you use a USB connector, someone will eventually connect it to an actual USB hub (or other USB device)!!

Comment: @arc_lupus  How long are the I2C wires going to be?  I2C bus was not conceived for cables, although you may be able to get away with it.  Just a heads-up.

Comment: Wires are around 1-2 m, not more. Should I use something else instead of I2C for transporting data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some I2C interfaces on the market (MCC iPort for instance) use AMP 4-1761206-1 connectors, for which pre-fabricated cables are readily available.

[image]

You could also go with RJ-11 if you're not worried about shielding (as long as no one connects your board to the PSTN...)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

I use this type of flat cables. They are reliable to use.

Comment: Looks like a fun project, Orkun :)

Comment: More fun than it looks!

Answer (score 1):

My go-to solution for something like this is just female headers on the board, ribbon cable with male headers soldered on for the cable. I will often use an extra pin clipped off with the hole in the female header plugged with a piece of wire. This keeps me from plugging it in backward.